# CompletableFutures and filtering based on values that are inside

Tags: java, lambda, filter, java-8, completable-future

I'm in a bit of confusion right now, so I have a method that should return `CompletableFuture<List<A>>`

inside the method is:

```
CompletableFuture<List<String>> toReturn = asyncCall().thenApply(....)
.thenCompose(listOfStuff -> convertToList(listOfStuff.stream().map(
     key -> asyncCall2(key)
        .thenApply(optionalValue -> optionalValue.orElse(null))
).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

and `convertToList()` simply joins futures to convert `CompletableFuture<List<ComputableFuture<A>>>` into `CompletableFuture<List<A>>`

Basically my intention is to filter null values that emerge from `optionalValue.orElse(null)` And it would be easy to do filter before collecting it all to list in the last line, but if I use it just before `.collect` it is working over CompletableFutures

I suspect there's a lot of restructuring I can do in my code.

EDIT:

```
private<T> CompletableFuture<List<T>> convertToList(List<CompletableFuture<T>> toConvert) {
    return CompletableFuture.allOf(toConvert.toArray(new CompletableFuture[toConvert.size()]))
            .thenApply(v -> toConvert.stream()
                    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
            );
}
```

Comment: Use `Stream.of()` and `Stream.empty()` ?

Comment: Don’t call `.orElse(null)`, then you don’t need to test for `null`. So the parameter type of `convertToList` would be `List<CompletableFuture<Optional<T>>>` and it can just do a `.filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get)` after the `join`…

Comment: @Holger yes, it's an option to do filtering (either on optionals or null values) in `convertToList`, I'd like to do everything in one place though, and `convertToList` can be a universal utility function

Comment: Why not just write a utility function that goes `List<Option<T>> -> List<T>` ?

Answer (score 2):

The best way would probably be to change `convertToList()` so that it does not return a future of list, but of stream instead:

```
private <T> CompletableFuture<Stream<T>> convertToFutureOfStream(List<CompletableFuture<T>> toConvert) {
    return CompletableFuture.allOf(toConvert.stream().toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new))
            .thenApply(
                    v -> toConvert.stream()
                            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
            );
}
```

This will be more reusable as the method will allow better chaining and will not force the caller to work with a list, while still allowing to easily get a list with a simple collect.

You can then simply filter that stream to remove empty optionals:

```
CompletableFuture<List<String>> toReturn = asyncCall()
    .thenCompose(listOfStuff -> convertToFutureOfStream(
            listOfStuff.stream()
                    .map(this::asyncCall2)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
        )
        .thenApply(stream ->
                stream.filter(Optional::isPresent)
                        .map(Optional::get)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        )

    );
```

You can even improve this a little further by changing `convertToFutureOfStream()` to take a stream as argument as well:

```
private <T> CompletableFuture<Stream<T>> convertToFutureOfStream(Stream<CompletableFuture<T>> stream) {
    CompletableFuture<T>[] futures = stream.toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
    return CompletableFuture.allOf(futures)
            .thenApply(v -> Arrays.stream(futures).map(CompletableFuture::join));
}
```

(unfortunately this raises an unchecked assignment warning because of the array of generic types)

Which then gives

```
CompletableFuture<List<String>> toReturn = asyncCall()
    .thenCompose(listOfStuff -> convertToFutureOfStream(
                listOfStuff.stream().map(this::asyncCall2)
            )
        .thenApply(stream ->
                stream.filter(Optional::isPresent)
                        .map(Optional::get)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        )

    );
```